# Elixir: When to use .ex and when .exs files

Tags: elixir

Elixir's documentation [states](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#scripted-mode) that

> In addition to the Elixir file extension .ex, Elixir also supports
>   .exs files for scripting. Elixir treats both files exactly the same
>   way, the only difference is in intention. .ex files are meant to be
>   compiled while .exs files are used for scripting, without the need for
>   compilation.

But I'm still not sure when to use which file type. What are the downsides and the purpose of .ex and .exs?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`.ex` is for compiled code, `.exs` is for interpreted code.

ExUnit tests, for example, are in `.exs` files so that you don't have to recompile every time you make a change to your tests. If you're writing scripts or tests, use `.exs` files. Otherwise, just use `.ex` files and compile your code.

As far as pros/cons, interpretation will take longer to execute (as elixir has to parse, tokenize, etc.), but doesn't require compilation to run. That's pretty much it - if the flexibility of running scripts is more important than optimized execution time, use `.exs`. Most of the time, you'll use `.ex`.

Answer (score 11):

Elixir will compile the whole `.ex` file.

`.exs` files are compiled as well but are meant to be executed when invoked. So, most use cases of `.exs` files are to execute code immediately when called. Think of using `.exs` files for testing, migrating data and running scripts. Think of `.ex` files as being used for your application's main business logic.

Consider this example

**`.ex` sample**

`sum.ex`:

```
defmodule Sum do
  def add(a, b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

```
$ iex sum.ex
...

Interactive Elixir (1.9.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> Sum.add(1, 2)
3
```

**`.exs` sample**

`sum.exs`:

```
defmodule Sum do
  def add(a, b)  do
    a + b
  end
end

#within same file

IO.puts "The sum of 3 + 2 is: #{inspect Sum.add(3, 2)}"
```

```
$ elixir sum.exs
The sum of 3 + 2 is: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

I check it in Elixir version 1.9.1 and both extensions `.ex`, `.exs` will be compiled with `elixirc`. Another words,  we get bytecode (`.beam` file) in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

For some more concrete details, here are some patterns or rules of thumb I've noticed about when to use `.ex` vs `.exs` files:

Almost all code goes in an `.ex` file in my application's 'library' directory tree, e.g. under `lib` (or maybe `web` if the application is an old Phoenix webapp). The code can be called (if it defines public functions or macros) elsewhere in the application or from `iex`. This is the default.

Probably the most important consideration for deciding between `.ex` and `.exs` is where (and when) I want to call that code:

1. In the application itself – `.ex`
2. From `iex` (e.g. `iex -S mix`) – `.ex`, if the code is also (or probably will be) used by the application; `.exs` for 'ad-hoc' scripts, e.g. for a specific bug or other issue
3. From the shell, via `mix` – `.ex` for custom Mix tasks, or as data in `mix.exs` (for simple task aliases)
4. From the shell, i.e. as a 'regular script' – `.exs` and run via `elixir some-script.exs`.

What may be surprising is that a good bit of code that starts as one of [2], [3], or [4], eventually ends up in [1] anyways.

And a really important thing to keep in mind is that it's EASY to move code from, e.g. an `.exs` file to an `.ex` file (or vice versa).

For [2], and for one application in particular, I setup some extra 'scripts mode' Mix environments for use with `iex`. Basically, they run a basic 'dev' local instance of (parts of) the app, but connect to the production/staging DB (or other backend services). I have some helper functions/macros for these 'command environments' but mostly I just use application code to, e.g. query the production/staging database and fix/cleanup/inspect some data. If I *do* need to do something that's even a little 'involved' (complicated), I'll usually create an ad-hoc 'issue script'. It's much easier to *write* code in my editor than in `iex`.

For ad-hoc scripts for [2], I have a `dev/scripts` sub-directory-tree in one project and mostly just name ad-hoc scripts based on the corresponding ticket number (from that project's ticket system), ex. `123.exs`. Then, in `iex`, I can easily run that script:

```
iex> c "dev/scripts/123.exs"
```

One nice 'workflow' is to just define a single (top-level) module in the script file:

```
defmodule Ticket123 do

  ...

  def do_some_one_off_thing ...

end
```

Then, from `iex`:

```
iex> c "dev/scripts/123.exs"
[Ticket123]
iex> Ticket123.do_some_one_off_thing ...
Something something
...
```

For [3], both task aliases in your project's `mix.exs` and 'fully' custom Mix tasks are really nice.

Some example aliases from one project:

- Run 'all' migrations – this project has regular (`Ecto`) database migrations AND some migrations that we want to run 'manually' (i.e. using the 'scripts mode' environments mentioned above). We use manual migrations for things like long-running database queries/commands, ex. adding or modifying an index on a big table.
- Deploy to staging/production
- `test` – this shadows the builtin Mix task to perform some custom local-database setup
- `todo` – output search results for TODO comments in our (Elixir) code

Some example custom tasks from the same project:

- `Mix.Tasks.OneProject.BootstrapServer` – some custom { configuration management / automated infrastructure deployment } code
- `Mix.Tasks.OneProject.DbSetup` – pulls some configuration data from the Elixir app but mostly just passes that to a shell script
- `Mix.Tasks.OneProject.ImportTranslations` – downloads translations and other internationalization data from a third-party
- `Mix.Tasks.OneProject.RollingDeploy` – custom deployment that uses something like a 'blue-green' model, but with a load balancer instead of two entirely separate environments/instances

I haven't used entirely 'regular' Elixir script files much at all in any project – to be called via `elixir some-script.exs`. Probably the biggest reason not to, i.e. to just create a custom Mix task or an 'issue script', is that custom Mix tasks are nicely documented, i.e. via `mix help` and `mix help some-custom-mix-task`, and I *really* like working at a REPL (`iex`).