# Elixir -- Module was not compiled with docs

Tags: documentation, elixir, elixir-iex

I just started learning elixir yesterday. I have a file User.exs.  It looks like this:

```
defmodule User do
    @moduledoc """ 
    Defines the user struct and functions to handle users.
    """
    # functions and stuff go here...

end
```

When I run `iex`, this is what happens when I try to see the docs:

```
iex(1)> c "user.exs"
[User]
iex(2)> h User
User was not compiled with docs
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the extension of the file to be `.ex`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Problem remains, no different.

Comment: Normally a .exs is not compiled (it's a script file).  So @mudasobwa's suggestion is a good one.  But if you're not using a mix file then I'd suggest you add one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`c("user.exs")` compiles the file in memory and does not write the bytecode (.beam file) to disk while `h/1` currently requires (details below) the beam file to be present on disk to work. You can make `c` store the generated bytecode in the current directory which will make `h/1` work with `c("user.exs", ".")`:

```
$ ls
user.exs
$ cat user.exs
defmodule User do
  @moduledoc """
  Defines the user struct and functions to handle users.
  """
end
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.4.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c("user.exs", ".")
[User]
iex(2)> h User

                                      User

Defines the user struct and functions to handle users.

iex(3)>
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
^C
$ ls
Elixir.User.beam user.exs
```

---

`h/1` relies on `Code.get_docs/2` to fetch the documentation which calls `:code.get_object_code/1` on the module. `:code.get_object_code/1` according to [its docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#get_object_code-1), "Searches the code path for the object code of module Module. Returns `{Module, Binary, Filename}` if successful, otherwise `error`."

Answer (score 11):

The reason is that `*.exs` files are for scripting and they won't be compiled and `*.ex` files will be compiled by elixir.

If you have no mix project and the `user.ex` file only then try `elixirc user.ex` and after this start `iex` and type `h User`.

If you have a mix project then start iex like so from the command line: `iex -S mix`
This will load your project and compiles all `*.ex` files. Now type `h User`.

I tried both ways by myself and both work.

See also:

- [Scripted Mode](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#scripted-mode)
- [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292620/elixir-when-to-use-ex-and-when-exs-files).

Comment: Note that the extension doesn't matter with `elixirc`. `elixirc user.exs` also works.