# r(module_name) not reloading @doc in iex

Tags: elixir, reload, elixir-iex

I am updating my @doc while in iex> to test how it looks. The problem I am coming up against is that I have to exit iex to view the updated @doc documentation. Is there a way to reload the modules @doc variables when using r()?

```
iex -S mix 
iex> h Coordinate.island/1 
      ## Examples 
      iex> {:ok, coord } = Cordinate.start_link
         Cordinate.island(coord) 
         :falls_town
```

Updated @doc to return :none instead of :falls_town and save file.

```
iex> r(Coordinate) 
iex> h Coordinate.island/1 
   # issue: still showing the old @doc example 
   ## Examples 
   iex> {:ok, coord } = Cordinate.start_link
        Cordinate.island(coord) 
        :falls_town # should be :none
```

Comment: Try running `recompile()` instead of `r(...)` in `iex -S mix`.

Comment: @Dogbert that worked thanks a lot! So I in order to reload doc variables you have to recompile the current Mix application.

Answer (score 5):

[`h/1` currently loads the documentation from the compiled .beam files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512734/320615). `r/1` compiles the files in memory and does not write the .beam files to disk, which means that `h/1` does not reload the docs when you run `r/1`:

> When we reload the module in IEx, we recompile the module source code,
>   updating its contents in memory. The original .beam file in disk,
>   probably the one where the first definition of the module came from,
>   does not change at all.

[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#r/1)

You can compile the package and write the resulting .beam files to disk by running `recompile/0` in `iex` (instead of `r/1`). After running that, you should see the new documentation in `h/1`.