# Debug phoenix test with IEx

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I know you can debug the webapp with IEx but is it possible to set a breakpoint inside a test?

For example in the following test I would like to check what's inside conn or check any other variable or macro.

```
defmodule HelloWeb.PageControllerTest do
  use HelloWeb.ConnCase
  require IEx
  test "GET /", %{conn: conn} do
    IEx.pry
    conn = get conn, "/"
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Welcome to Phoenix!"
  end
end
```

In order to make it work with the webapp you must have phoenix.server running with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`

But in this case is a test not the webapp so it complains with:

```
Cannot pry #PID<0.406.0> at ... Is an IEx shell running?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check what is inside conn structure (or any other variable) you can just use `IO.inspect conn` and run tests as usual with `mix test` - there is no need to use pry here. For example:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.PageControllerTest do
  use HelloWeb.ConnCase
  test "GET /", %{conn: conn} do
    IO.inspect conn, limit: :infinity
    conn = get conn, "/"
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Welcome to Phoenix!"
  end
end
```

However, if you really need a shell you can then call it like this:

```
iex -S mix test
```

Answer (score 2):

ExUnit tests are in .exs files that mean interpreted code is written in it. So you can't set break point in it.

For more informations about .exs and .ex file. See  [Elixir: When to use .ex and when .exs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292620/elixir-when-to-use-ex-and-when-exs-files)

If you want to check any map simply write

```
    IO.inspect conn
```

And for simple variable you can write

```
    IO.puts variable_name
```